# Upload Synonyms file in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm new to ElasticSearch. I'm working on setting up synonyms in ElasticSearch as explained in this [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html).

Can someone help me on how to upload the synonym.txt to the ElasticSearch in order to refer it in the settings?

Comment: Can you tell what "elasticsearch" are you talking about ? is that Cloud based elastic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are new to ES, would suggest you another way to use the synonym using the filter as shown in the same official link which you mentioned.

```
  "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "lenient": true,
            "synonyms": [ "foo, bar => baz" ] // please note this
          }
```

Still, if you want to use the file based synonym than you can simply ssh into your ES server as place your file as explained in the official doc

> The above configures a synonym filter, with a path of
> analysis/synonym.txt (relative to the config location). The synonym
> analyzer is then configured with the filter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have around 200 synonyms to be added. Hence, I preferred the file approach.

Are there any blog posts that helps me on how to SSH into the ES server and place the file in the config location.

Comment: if you dont know how to ssh and copy file, how do you install elasticsearch?

Comment: I installed ElasticSearch through docker.

Comment: @Ancita you can use the docker volume https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ to mount local dir to docker container and this way you don't have to ssh and copy your file.